# Count of messages in rabbitMQ queue using spring boot

Tags: spring-boot, rabbitmq

i wanted help regarding how to save the count of messages in a RabbitMQ queue to an object. so this data can be used by some other functionality. I found some answers but not for Spring boot. Please help!

Answer (score 0):

The AMQP protocol in the Spring Boot application is based on the Spring AMQP project.

For your task to reach as high API level as possible you can do like this:

```
@Autowired
private RabbitTemplate rabbitTemplate;
...

AMQP.Queue.DeclareOk declareOk = this.rabbitTemplate.execute(channel -> 
                        channel.queueDeclare(QUEUE_NAME, true, false, false, queueArgs));

declareOk.getMessageCount();
```

And apply appropriate queue options for that `queueDeclare()`.